# Do ports placed in a blocking state by STP still forward normal traffic?

Tags: networking, router, switch

I'm working on studying for Cisco certs and this is confusing me a bit. I know that ports can either be in forwarding, filtering, or blocking states, but are those states related to the STP states? For example, if a port is in a learning state and building a database of bridges for STP, is it also blocking the transmission of normal non-STP or BPDU traffic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal traffic is blocked when the STP state is not forwarding. Otherwise, there could be loops and network meltdowns.

Comment: Thanks for the straightforward reply. This really helped.